# コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観とは

Tags: 討議, 完了

A lot of thanks to [@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation.

---

コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観とは、より複雑で重要な決定を下すために私たちが用いる意思決定における原則（ガイドライン）であり経験則です。それらがコミュニティのルールを理解するための基盤となります。経験豊富なユーザーがシステムでのやり取りについて回答した場合、価値観はより経験豊富なユーザーから新しいユーザーへと渡されます。

私たちが大切にしたい価値観について話し合い、それらをヘルプセンターに追加しませんか？そうすることによって私達が日本語版コミュニティ独自の文化を長期的に維持し、日本語版コミュニティの基準で新しいユーザーを導く効果を高めることができます。

以下はヘルプセンター記事のドラフトです。みなさんどうぞ編集してくださいね！

> **コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観:**
>
> ## 1. ユーザー第一
>
> - **グループ内では - 互いにどのように接するかが重要な成功基準です**。私たちの主となる目標はコミュニティを共に築きそして支援することです。他はその後に続きます。
> - **Be Nice.  サイト上でのやり取りは、信用度や専門知識、年齢やアイデンティティなどに関わらず、仲間への相互の尊重**から始まります。
> - 私たちのコミュニティでは、[**全ての人が温かく迎えられ**](/conduct)、質問や回答を投稿することができます。
>
> ## 2. 日本語での*質の良い*プログラミングに関する知識が多ければ多いほど良いです！
>
> - **スタック・オーバーフローは既成の解決方法のライブラリ**であり、最小のノイズで最大のシグナルを持ち、最も結晶化された形で問題(質問)と解決策(回答)が並んでいます。
> - **質問と回答を投稿するのは一回ですがその後に何百万回も読まれます**。サイト上のすべてのコンテンツは検索してサイトにアクセスするプログラマーの閲覧用に最適化されています。
> - **まず第一にコミュニティにとって有益なコンテンツを持つことが重要です。作成方法は副次的に過ぎません。** 盗用を除いて、サイト上で*役に立つ*知識を作成する様々な方法を歓迎します。認められている方法は次の通りです:
>
>   - [ベストプラクティス、自己回答式](/help/self-answer);
>   - [英語の質問からの翻訳](/help/translate-from-english);
>   - コミュニティWikiの質問;
>
> そしてもちろんあなたが現在抱える問題の投稿も推奨されています。どのような問題でもまずは質問してみましょう。投稿する前に「[良い質問をするには](/help/how-to-ask)」に目を通すことをお忘れなく。
>
> ## 3. 素晴らしいコミュニティを共に築きましょう
>
> - **スタック・オーバーフローはプログラミングに関するより良い知識を集結するための総体的な取り組みです。** このサイトはあなたと同じような多くのアクティブユーザーの協力のおかげで存在しています。
> - **日本語を話すプログラマーコミュニティ全体のために力を合わせて有用な知識を蓄積します。** 日本語を話すプログラマーなら誰でも無料でスタック・オーバーフローの質問や回答を使って問題解決を行うことができます。質問を投稿する際、過剰にへりくだる必要はありません。そして円滑なコミュニケーションを図る為に「ネガティブなネットスラング」や「強い言葉」を避けましょう。
> - **互いの協力によってコミュニティが存在します。** コミュニティの在り方についてはメタで話し合い、私たちの手でスタック・オーバーフローの方向性を決めることができます。

---

あなたが個人的に大切にしている価値観とはどのようなものか、そして日本語版コミュニティにはさほど大切ではない価値観が上にもし書かれていればそれもあわせて共有してください。ヘルプセンターに追加するためには上の文章にどのような変更を加えれば良いでしょうか？

あなたのアイデアや提案をお聞かせください！共に私たちのコミュニティをさらに良くしていきましょう。

---

**Update**

ご意見ありがとうございました！ヘルプセンターに「コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観」のリンクが追加されました。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values＼(^o^)／

Comment: 新しいヘルプセンターの記事をこのまま追加してもよろしいでしょうか？もっと話し合う時間が必要であれば教えて下さい。特になければ来週の月曜日に記事を追加予定です。

Comment: @Community　タイトルは現在「コミュニティの主な価値」となっていますが、改善案として「コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観」はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 英語版wikiの`Great man theory`にリンクを貼っているようですが、日本のコミュニティでは関連性がいまいち伝わらないのではないかと思いました。（そもそも意味が通じるかという問題も……）

Comment: @Sieg ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。リンクを削除してもよろしいでしょうか？実は、ロシア語版では、削除しました。

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky (1) タイトルを「コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観」に変えていただけますか？　(2) Sieg さんのおっしゃるとおり、リンクを削除して良いと思います。

Comment: @nekketsuuu フレーズ全体を削除する必要があると判断した場合（「1人の偉人ではない」）またはリンクのみを削除した場合について、明確にしてください。

Comment: @Sieg さん、私はリンクだけで良いと思うのですが、如何でしょうか？　少し言い方を変えるとしたら「このサイトは、特定の偉い人ではなくあなたと同じような多くのアクティブユーザーの協力のおかげで存在しています。」くらいでしょうか……。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、@Sieg さん、@community「このサイトはあなたと同じような多くのアクティブユーザーの協力のおかげで存在しています。」というフレーズで、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: @aki 良いですね！　賛成です。

Answer (score 6):

初心者の立場およびほぼ主観で回答させていただきます。
上記に挙げている価値観はどれも素晴らしいと思いますが、日本におけるネット界隈の暗黙の了解となっている部分がコミュニティ形成の妨げになっているように思えます。

私のようなプログラミング初心者の立場からすると、比較的簡単な問題でも質問をしたいのですが、過去にネットの掲示板などで「〇〇年ROMれ」や「ggrks」などといった言葉（もう古いネットスラングですが）を言われており、質問時の印象を考えるとどうしても躊躇してしまいます。また、他の質問を見てみてもニッチな質問や使用場面が限定的な質問が多く、「そのようなレベルでないといけないのか」や「このくらい知識を付けてからでないと質問や回答が難しい」と思ってしまいます。ネットだけでなく周りにいる人間も「ネットで探せ」と言うだけで教えてくれない場合が多いです。実際に、ネットで探せば確かに答えは見つかります。しかし、探すのに膨大な時間がかかり、学習が遅くなったり停滞することになります。
また、海外（英語版）Stack Over Flowと比べてみても質問者や回答者の雰囲気が違うように見えます。私自身英語を使うのは苦ではないので、基本的には英語のStack Over Flowを利用させていただいています。利用してみて、やはり海外の方が質問しやすい雰囲気があるように思えます。
一度、質問の文頭に「単純な質問で申し訳ありませんが…」といった内容を書いたことがありますが、編集され消されたことがあります。ただこの時、英語圏の文化的に「わざわざ断りを入れる必要はない」という印象を受けました。日本では逆に回答をいただく立場として低姿勢を示す必要があるので、断りを入れなければならないと感じることが多いと思います。
日本のとっつきにくさは言語による印象、日本の民族性や文化も関係しているのかもしれないですが、これらを改善していく方法があればいいなと思っています。

具体的なアイディアはまだありませんが、簡単な質問例やユーザー間でもっとフランクにやりとりしている場面が見れたら質問しやすい雰囲気になるのではと考えています。
また、ネットの暗黙の了解となっている部分を無視して質問できるような文言があればいいなと思います。「どんなことでもまずは聞いてみよう」といったものなど。もし質問がおかしかったり、自己解決できるようなものだったとしても、後から訂正文を入れるなり回答欄に自分で書いてしまうものでいいと思います。

長々ととっつきにくさを書きましたが、今後活躍する若い世代はもしかしたらこのようなことを気にしないかもしれません。そういった方々に期待したいと同時に、年齢問わずコミュニティの形成を行っていける環境ができあがればいいなと思っています。

ほぼ主観的な印象や価値観になりましたが、いち意見として受け取っていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: フィードバックありがとうございます。一緒に様々な問題について考えてみましょう。ヘルプセンター記事のドラフトの1. に「年齢」というワードを追加しました。

Comment: 私はそれが "インターネット上での検索"に関する一つの重要なSOルールを言及する価値があると思います：質問はSO上に存在し、重複として閉じるべきであるか、他のウェブサイト上に存在するかどうかにかかわらず尋ねられるべきです。Stack Overflowは、プログラミングに関するコミュニティの知識ベースを日本語で作成するという使命を持っています。 それは質問者への即時の援助についてではありません。

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky it's not quite the same...
Japan has many unfriendly net slang, so he says that hard to ask questions.
I think it means that want to dispel the atmosphere unique to Japan and to ques Frank more.
Does my English make sense?

Comment: Thanks to Sieg. He/she is exactly explaining what I was saying. In addition, in Japanese culture trying hard by yourselves is praised. So if I didn't try researching by myself at all I will be blamed a lot. Not taking any act and just asking someone else is not a good attitude but sometimes I do not want to struggle too much on my questions. However, I also wrote about young generations may not care about this because probably they haven't encountered such problems, and also they are truly digital natives so they may think things differently.

Comment: There is one more thing I forgot to mention about. Japanese people tend to feel shame when asking a question. When I was studying overseas (in UK) people were asking questions, but in Japan people do not ask so much. People feel that not knowing things are embarrassing, and pretend they know about it. I think this is a bad habit. However, I think the community should tell people at the first place that asking questions and not knowing things are not a shameful thing. I'm still bit afraid being blamed here, so I still tend to use the English version of Stack overflow.

Comment: @Tim あなたの洞察をどうもありがとうございました！ヘルプセンターであなたが言ったことすべてに対処する必要があると思います。特に：Stack Overflowは、最初はコミュニティの知識ベースであり、それ以降は、他のプログラマから回答が得られる場所になります。質問をする人は恥を感じるべきではありません。 彼らは、彼らがそのような素晴らしい無料の公共資産を創造するのを手助けしていることを歓迎し、賞賛するべきです。どう思いますか？ 我々はそれをすることができますか？

Comment: @Sieg 説明をありがとうございました。失礼は一般的にインターネット上で一般的であることを恐れています。いつかこの問題を解決することを願っています。

Comment: @Tim ご意見ありがとうございます。「どのような問題でもまずは質問してみましょう。」という文章をヘルプセンター記事のドラフト 2. に追加しました。

Comment: @Tim 日本語版で過剰にへりくだる必要はないという点をヘルプセンター記事のドラフト 3. に追加しました。もし「過剰」ではなく別のワードの方がフィットする場合は編集くださいね♬

Comment: @Sieg とTimさん コメントありがとうございます :)「ネガティブなネットスラング」を避けましょうという文言をヘルプセンター記事のドラフト 3. に追加しました。

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky I agree to what you say. The community should be a good place and every user should be proud of building the community together. あなたに同意します。すべてのユーザーはコミュニティを一緒に構築することに誇りを持つべきです。

Answer (score 5):

日本語のコミュニティなので、日本的価値感を切り離しては考えられないのだろと思っています。
　具体的には

- 強い言葉を使わない
- その様な言葉遣いをしている回答、コメントがあった場合、（第３者が）指摘出来る／する
- 指摘された場合に我を通さず、指摘を受け入れる
- 間違っていないと言うこととそれが正しいことは別物であることを意識する

事が大事なのでは無いかと思っています。

かつて行った回答とそれに続くコメントで過剰にへりくだったコメントが帰ってきた際に、無自覚に相手を不愉快にさせてしまっていたんだなと感じてから、上記はより意識して回答する様にしています。

僕も過去に質問した際に「お前は馬鹿だ」や「そんな風に考えるなんておかしい」の婉曲的表現として主に使われる言葉を回答に書かれ、うんざりして日本語SOから離れていました。今でも割り切れていませんが、回答が付かない質問に答えることで役に立てるならと、回答が付かない質問で僕が答えられる質問があるときのみ、回答しようというスタンスで戻ってきた感じです。

Comment: フィードバックありがとうございます。「強い言葉」を避けましょうという文言をヘルプセンター記事のドラフト 3. に追加しました。

Comment: ドラフトの3.を拝見させていただきました。言いたかった事がとてもうまくまとまっていると思います。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 4):

自分の中では、このコミュニティの目的は、以下になるんだろうなと思っています。

1. プログラマーのために、プログラミングに関する知見を Q&A で集積する。
2. それを日本語で行う。
3. Be Nice

個人的な感覚としては、諸々の価値観は上の３つに集約されていて、普段行動するにあたってはこれを原則として、アクションを取っているような気がします。

Comment: フィードバックありがとうございます。ヘルプセンター記事のドラフト 3. に「Be Nice」を一旦追加しましたが、1. の方がよりフィットすると思いましたので移動させてください。

Comment: @Community 「Be Nice」は現在英語のまま使用していますが、日本語では何と訳せば良いでしょうか？それとも英語の「Be Nice」をこれからも使用する方がベターでしょうか？